# NodeJS: how to access TextRow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sequelize.js

I am using sequalize to fetch data with node and angular but I am getting the below result.

result:

```
count---- [ TextRow { totalCount: 39, total_rating: 0, number_of_review: null } ]
```

Now I want to return `totalCount` from above result. I have tried everything but not able to access it.

Comment: how you are printing the above statement?

Comment: I have console log it returned output.

Comment: Not able to access with dot notation

Comment: try output[0].totalCount

Comment: can i post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
output[0].totalCount
```

I am considering output as your property name. in console it is displayed as array. Thats why i am getting index 0 then totalCount property of object at index 0.

Comment: Try it *where*? How/why does your proposed solution fix the problem? More context will make a better answer, and as a bonus your answer won't be flagged as low quality (and probably deleted) due to length.

Comment: @Caleb updated above, there was a network issue and i didn't check it.